# Unable to safely remove Seagate 1TB external device from ubuntu. It reconnects and the device browser opens automatically.

Tags: external-hdd

I'm unable to safely remove the external device from the system as it reconnects automatically and I am afraid that removing it forcefully while it's still connected with the LED glowing might corrupt the data.

Is there anything that could be done to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, if no software solution works, you can do a hard system shutdown.  An orderly shutdown will unmount all storage devices harmlessly, and once the system is powered down, you can disconnect the external drive.

However, I'd look for what keeps reconnecting the external drive, and try to get that to stop.  It might be that some software on your system expects to find that storage, and it'll fail once you restart if you do a shutdown-disconnect-restart cycle.

Comment: Well, That's all I could do initially for a couple of times, but then I realised that I was facing this issue only with the USB 3.0 ports but not the USB 2.0 ones.